# Unable to use locally built python package in development mode

Tags: pip, python-3.6, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to spin up a super simple package for proof of concept and I can't see what i'm missing.

My aim is to be able to do the following:

```
python3 import mypackage
mypackage.add2(2)
>> 4
```

### Github link

**I created a public repo to reproduce the issue [here](https://github.com/OliverFarren/testPackage)**

```
git clone https://github.com/OliverFarren/testPackage
```

### Problem

I have a basic file structure as follows:

```
src/
   mypackage/
      __init__.py
      mymodule.py
setup.cfg
setup.py
pyproject.toml
```

setup.cfg is pretty boiler plate from [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html)

setup.py is just to allow pip install in editable mode:

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```

I ran the following commands at the top level directory in my Pycharm virtual env:

```sh
python3 -m pip install --upgrade build
python3 -m build
```

That created my `dist` and `build` directories and `mypackage.egg-info` file so now the directory looks like this:

```
testpackage
 build/
   bdist.linux-x86_64/
 dist/
   mypackage-0.1.0.tar.gz
   mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
 src/
   mypackage/
      mypackage.egg-info
      __init__.py
      mymodule.py
 setup.cfg
 setup.py
 pyproject.toml
```

I've then tried install the package as follows:

```
sudo pip3 install -e .
```

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Installing collected packages: mypackage
  Running setup.py develop for mypackage
Successfully installed mypackage
```

Which I think should have installed it. Except when I try and import the package I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`

I'm wondering whether this is a permissions issue of some sort. When I try:

```
sudo pip3 list
pip3 list
```

I notice i'm getting different outputs, I can see my package present in the list and in my sys.path:

```
~/testpackage/src/mypackage'
```

I just don't understand what i'm missing here. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't use sudo with pip.

Comment: Thankyou for posting this, I didn't realise there was issues with sudo and pip before now. Now I've learned there's a risk in giving root access to malicious packages so won't be doing this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the issue. Posting solution and leaving the github repo live - with fix, incase anyone else has this issue.

It turns out my `setup.cfg` *wasn't* boiler plate.

Here was my incorrect code:

```
[metadata]
# replace with your username:
name = mypackage
author = Oliver Farren
version = 0.1.0
description = Test Package

classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
package_dir =
    = src/mypackage
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src/mypackage
```

`src/mypackage` should be `src`, it was looking *inside* the package for packages.

A key step in debugging this issue was checking the `mypackage.egg.info` files. The `SOURCES.txt` contained a list of all the files in the build package and I could clearly see that in the incorrect build, that `src/mypackage/mymodules.py` and `src/mypackage/__init__.py` were missing. So the package was correctly installed by pip, but being empty was making for a very confusing error message.